# Обход бинарного дерева с использованием стека

Tags: c, дерево, бинарное-дерево

нужно создать функцию обхода бинарного дерева в симметричном порядке с помощью стека. 
проблема функции мне понятна, поясню на примере дерева из семи элементов:

первым выводится самый левый элемент. он будет иметь уровень 3. используется цикл *while* для вывода пробелов. значит, вспомогательная переменная *i* примет значение 3. вторым выведется родитель прошлого элемента. этот элемент имеет уровень 2, но вспомогательная переменная уже равна 3. поэтому второй элемент выведется вообще без пробелов. как видите, вывод уже нарушен.

```
typedef struct tree
{
    int value;
    struct tree *l, *r;
} tree;

typedef struct stack
{
    tree *previous;
    int level;
    struct stack *next;
} stack;

int is_empty(stack **top) //проверка стека на наличие элементов
{
    return *top == NULL;
}

void add_s(stack **top, tree **cur, int lvl) //добавление элемента в стек 
{
    stack *node = (stack*)malloc(sizeof(stack));
    node->previous = *cur;
    node->level = lvl;
    node->next = NULL;
    if(!is_empty(top))
        node->next = *top;
    (*top) = node;
}

void del(stack **top) //удаление элемента из стека
{
    stack *node;
    if(!is_empty(top))
    {
        node = *top;
        *top = (*top)->next;
        free(node);
        node = NULL;
    }
}

void symmetric(tree **root, stack **top, int c) //косячная функция вывода дерева
{
    bool stop;
    int level = 0, i = 1;
    tree *current;
    current = *root;
    stop = false;
    while(!stop)
    {
        while(current != NULL)
        {
            ++level;
            add_s(top, &current, level);
            current = current->l;
        }
        if (is_empty(top))
            stop = true;
        else
        {
            current = (*top)->previous;
            while(i < (*top)->level)
            {
                printf("     ");
                ++i;
            }
            del(top);
            printf("%d \n", current->value);
            current = current->r;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Запоминайте в стеке `level` вместе с `current`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

справился я с этой проблемой. нужно было хранить уровень элемента не в стеке, а в самом дереве. тогда все получается предельно просто.

```
typedef struct tree
{
    int value;
    struct tree *l, *r;
    int level;
} tree;

typedef struct stack
{
    tree *previous;
    struct stack *next;
} stack;

void add(tree **cur, int c, int level)
{
    tree *temp;
    int left, right;
    if(c == 0)
        *cur = NULL;
    else
    {
        left = c / 2;
        right = c - left - 1;
        temp = (tree*)malloc(sizeof(tree));
        temp->value = rand();
        temp->level = level;
        add(&temp->l, left, level + 1);
        add(&temp->r, right, level + 1);
        *cur = temp;
    }
}

void symmetric(tree **root, stack **top, int c)
{
    bool stop;
    int i = 1;
    tree *current;
    current = *root;
    stop = false;
    while(!stop)
    {
        while(current != NULL)
        {
            add_s(top, &current);
            current = current->l;
        }
        if (is_empty(top))
            stop = true;
        else
        {
            i = 0;
            current = (*top)->previous;
            while(i < current->level)
            {
                printf("     ");
                ++i;
            }
            del(top);
            printf("%d \n", current->value);
            current = current->r;
        }
    }
}
```